# Printing with the zebra sdk through usb android

Tags: android

is zebra sdk support printing data through android device usb cable?(with out wifi and bluetooth)

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please do your own searching before asking here...http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/adapt-software/zebralink-sdk-android.html

Comment: Thanks Tim for your reply i already downloaded SDK and executing sample application(It is giving some exceptions for me).But i am unable to understand will it support printing through USB?  From Sample application i found code for TCP and Bluetooth.

Comment: The same discussed here:https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=forums&topic=0217170180c7012f82b57ceb007a15

Comment: I would guess that it is possible with the ADK. I don't have any experience with that zebra stuff to know whether they've done the heavy lifting that would be required to get them talking correctly. If not it is still possible just someone else would have to do that heavy lifting

Comment: @smdu did you find any support or workaround with USB connection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to print via USB to a Zebra card printer using the Android SDK. I'm having troubles getting the varnish layer to appear, however, which might not be an issue for your application.